# Execute code after a window is displayed

Tags: winapi, event-loop

I'm working on a windows application where I'm implementing the whole event loop and everything like that myself (there's a reason for that).  In one place, I need to execute some code AFTER a window is shown.  Normally, when the window is created, I do some initialisation when WM_CREATE message is received. WM_SHOWWINDOW is sent just BEFORE the window is displayed. However I need to get some code executed right AFTER the window is displayed for the first time. I can't seem to find a notification message sent AFTER the window is shown.  Could it be that there isn't one?

Of course, I can keep a boolean - FirstRun - indicating whether or not I had performed my logic, and then execute the code when WM_ACTIVATE is received, provided the boolean is TRUE, then set FirstRun to FALSE so that the code is not execute the next time I am receive WM_ACTIVATE, but this seems somewhat unnatural to me.

It's been ages since I did win32 programming on this level, so can't remember much of it. What is the best approach here?

Comment: Can you listen for `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` messages and test for the `SWP_SHOWWINDOW` flag?

Comment: This isn't going to work, as the window can be shown and hidden several times throughout the application - but this code needs to be executed only on the first 'show'.

Comment: Well, keep track of whether or not you have ever reacted to this and only react once.

Comment: Yes, that's what I wrote in the second paragraph.  I was hoping there's a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no special notification, but in many cases you can use this trick:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MainWndProc(
HWND hwnd,        // handle to window
UINT uMsg,        // message identifier
WPARAM wParam,    // first message parameter
LPARAM lParam)    // second message parameter
{ 
switch (uMsg) 
{ 
    case WM_USER + 100:
        //window is just displayed, do some actions
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam); 
    case WM_CREATE:
        PostMessage(hwnd, WM_USER + 100, 0, 0);
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    default: 
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam); 
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1: I've done this successfully in the past. Although theoritically, one should bear in mind that WM are pulled out of the queue using some priorities. IIRC WM_PAINT has low priority. But the trick works anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one because that's what WM_SHOWWINDOW is for. Once that mesage is passed to the default message handling procedure, the window will be shown. The best thing you could do is poll with [IsWindowVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633530%28VS.85%29.aspx) via some sort of timer.

Your program design seems flawed though to have to rely on something like this. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are implementing the whole event loop and everything like that yourself, you can handle this directly in WinMain() like this:

```
HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(...);

if (!hWnd) return 0;

ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
UpdateWindow(hWnd);

OnWindowJustDisplayed();    // here

MSG msg;
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```